# Has Drax in fact mastered the ability to stand so still that he becomes invisible?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, drax-the-destroyer

In the MCU (I have never read the Guardians in comics) Drax seems to never consciously lie. Any time he speaks it seems as though he tells the 'truth' as he understands it and of course is completely literal when doing so. I do not remember him ever embellishing any truths to seem more grandiose than he actually is; others do that for him.

During *Infinity War* there is a scene where Gamora is speaking to Quill and she gets him to swear that he will kill her if Thanos captures her because she knows something he doesn't. As this scene starts the camera moves forward, about 10-15 feet, into the area where the two will talk. It moves between two massive cylinder things; centered between and in front of which is a small table. There is nothing in between these cylinders as the camera moves forward...

As Gamora and Quill begin to kiss we hear off-screen a crunching noise and the camera reveals Drax loudly crunching on some nuts. He is standing in between the two cylinders, nearly leaning on the right cylinder. This sparks the dialogue:

> Quill: Dude, how long have you been standing there? 
>   Drax: An hour. 
>   Quill: An hour? 
>   Gamora: Are you serious? 
>   Drax: I've mastered the ability of standing so incredibly still that I become invisible to the eye. Watch. 
>   Quill: You're eating a zarg-nut. 
>   Drax: But my movement is so slow that it is imperceptible. 
>   Gamora: Mmm, no. 
>   Drax: I'm sure I'm invisible. 
>   Mantis: Hi, Drax. 
>   Drax: Dammit.

Drax was not visible standing there when we saw the spot previously and this dialogue obviously lasts less than an hour which sparks my question(s)... Was Drax standing there for an hour, or was he lying? If he was lying, has he done so knowingly previously? Or as I suspect, has he in fact mastered the ability to stand so still that he becomes invisible and he simply lost his concentration because he was hungry for a zarg-nut?

Comment: Have you tried staying still in a room before? Many of my friends didn't even notice me, despite clearly looking in my direction. The fact that he didn't appear on the camera might be to further emphasize that.

Comment: @Clockwork - I fear that your friends, just as mine would, likely did see you, but instead pretended you were not actually there... kind of like Cartman after he eats all the skin off the KFC...

Comment: ‘Standing so still that you become invisible’ doesn’t even make any sense. Any still, inanimate object (like the table you mention) would be invisible by default otherwise, since they don’t move at all.

Comment: He wasn’t lying, he just believed he’d mastered the ability of becoming invisible.

Comment: I will say being invisible by moving very fast is more plausible. Mountain Everest isn't invisible.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You and some others are missing the point...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. He's not mastered the ability to stand "*so still that he becomes invisible*". They simply didn't notice him because he was **standing in the dark and not moving**.

> As Quill and Gamora got lost in each other, a loud crunch rippled through the room. **They looked across the room to find Drax, standing in the shadows,** eating a bag of zarg-nuts.
>
> ...
>
> "I've mastered the ability of standing so incredibly still that I've
> become invisible to the eye. Watch." Drax's voice was mysterious and
> serious as he pulled a zarg-nut from the bag and lifted it to his
> mouth. **Fully visible. To everyone. Not invisible at all.** "You...you're
> eating a zarg-nut." Quill couldn't stand whatever Drax was doing for one
> more second.
>
> <sub><sup>[Avengers: Infinity War - Destiny Arrives](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War_-_Destiny_Arrives)</sup></sub>

---

That being said, you're not wrong. When the camera pulls towards Gamora and Quill he's **not** in the shot and when we look back in the opposite direction, he's there. This is more likely to be intended as comic effect (he was probably just outside the shot behind the column and moved slightly into view of Quill and Gamora so he could get a better view) than to be taken literally.

[image]

Note that this isn't the first time Drax has surprised Quill, probably aided by the fact that he walks surprisingly quietly, that his skin matches the colour of the bulkheads and that Quill is notoriously *unperceptive* when he's concentrating on Gamora.

[image]
<sub><sup>**GOTG: 2**</sup></sub>

Answer (score 3):

Yes in comics Drax can be invisible, these are some of his powers:

- Superhuman strength, durability, speed and endurance.
- Flight.
- Rays of energy.
- Expert in the use of knives.
- Knows the location of Thanos at any moment.
- Psychic detection of others.
- Invisibility.

But if you refer to the MCU, it does not have that capacity, it's just a reference to its ability in comics.

Comment: What does "Ability to witness the location of Thanos" mean?  Because it *sounds* like it means "if he sees Thanos, he knows where Thanos is", and I'm pretty sure that most people have that power.

Comment: It means that he knows where thanos is at any moment, sorry about my english i know that is a little bad.

Comment: @icortazar - Do you have any sources/proof of these abilities?!

Comment: I am a regular reader of comics, so the source is myself i guess XD